# Convex function has unique zero

Tags: real-analysis, roots

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable, convex function with $f(a) \gt 0$ and $f(b) \lt 0$. Then $f$ has a unique zero in $[a,b]$.

The existence of the zero follows immediately from the intermediate value theorem. But how am I going to prove that this zero is unique?

Comment: Remarking that $f'$ is increasing over $[a,b]$, we get that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/657456/418542) and [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996834/418542) are related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $a<x_1<x_2<b$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$. Then
$$x_2=tx_1+(1-t)b\quad \text{for $t=\frac{b-x_2}{b-x_1}\in (0,1)$}$$ and, by the [convexity of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) $f$,
$$0=f(x_2)=f(tx_1+(1-t)b)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(b)=(1-t)f(b)<0$$
which is a contradiction. There is no need of the derivative of $f$.

Comment: Silly question but $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)b$ for some $t\in (0, 1)$ relies on the convexity of $[a, b]$ and not $f$, correct?

Comment: I feel as if that should be proven as well, as that wasn't "given" in the question. Otherwise good answer!

Comment: @OriaGruber Actually $t=(b-x_2)/(b-x_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in (a,b)$  a zero. Since $f$ is convex, the graph of $f$ on $(c,b)$ is below the chord determined by $c$, $b$ , so below the $x$ axis. Conclusion: there are no zeroes to the right of any zero in $[a,b]$ ; thus, the zero is unique.