# Uniqueness of convex combination under strict quasiconcavity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly quasiconcave and continuous function and $f(x) < f(y)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is increasing such that $x_1 << x_2 $ ($x_2$ is elementwise greater than $x_1$) implies $f(x_1) < f(x_2) $. Consider a convex combination of $x$ and $y$, $\lambda x + (1- \lambda) y$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and the corresponding value of $f$ as $\overline{f}_\lambda = f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)$.

For a given $\lambda$, is it possible to find $\lambda' \neq \lambda $ such that $\overline{f}_\lambda = \overline{f}_{\lambda'}$? By the continuity of $f$ it is possible to find a value of $\lambda$ that satisfies $\overline{f}_\lambda = \overline{f}$ for some $\overline{f} \in (f(x), f(y))$, but I wonder if such decomposition is unique if $f$ is strictly quasiconcave. Note that for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniqueness can be relatively easily shown by a similar argument as in  [Convex function has unique zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616257/convex-function-has-unique-zero).

(edit: added an additional assumption that $f$ is increasing).

Comment: What is the definition of $x<<y$??

Comment: I meant $x_i < y_i$ for all $i = 1,...,n$ where $x_i, y_i$ are $i$th elements of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It can be shown that a strictly quasiconcave function has a unique maximizer $\mathbf{x}^*$, and also that the function is strictly increasing on the line segment from any point $\mathbf{y}\neq\mathbf{x}^*$ to $\mathbf{x}^*$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f(x)=-x^2$, $x=-1$, $y=2$. Then $f$ is not injective on $[x,y]$.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what happens if $f$ is increasing? I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate? I don't see it trivial especially given that the domain is multidimensional.

Comment: I thought about $f:R\to R$...

Comment: Even $f: R \to R$ case should be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I guess for $f: R \to R$ case the method is quite similar as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616257/convex-function-has-unique-zero.